# ST_Centroid in view produces geometry without further definition from geometry(polygon, ssid)

Tags: postgis-2.0

I'm a Postgresql novice.

In a postgresql 9.2 + PostGIS instance I have one table with a `geometry(polygon, ssid)` column. From this table I am trying to create a view using `ST_Centroid`  like so:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.polys_points AS 
   SELECT poly_table.name, 
          ST_Centroid(geom) as geom 
   FROM poly_table;
```

This produces a view with a `geometry()` column where I would like it defined as `geometry(point, ssid)` column. Is this possible?

Comment: How can I find a private key from an imported wallet?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158368)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158368)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158368)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but you can't do it after the view is created. Normally, the view would just inherit the geom constraints from the source table, but since you are changing the geom from polygon to point in your query, it won't automatically register. You just need to add typemods to your geom column within the view definition:

```
create or replace view schema.polys_points as 
select poly_table.name, ST_Centroid(geom)::geometry(POINT, SRID) as geom 
from poly_table;
```